# My recursion hang

Tags: haskell, recursion

It compiles correctly, but doesn't work.

It works for `[]` but if its anything else it just hang forever. `test1` - ok, `test 2` hang.

```
--Tests pour 'effectuerAchat'.
test1 = effectuerAchat achat1_1 [] == ([],achat1_1)
test2 = effectuerAchat achat1_1 [offre1_1_1_100] == ([(Commande "fournisseur1" "article1" 1 100)],Achat "article1" 0)
```

here is the code...

```
effectuerAchat a os = rfred a (offresPour a os) (achatQuantite(a)) []
   where rfred a os n lc = 
            if os == []|| n==0
            then (lc,(Achat (achatArticle(a)) n))
            else 
                 if n>=(offreQuantite(head(os)))
                 then let c= (Commande (offreFournisseur(head(os))) (achatArticle(a)) (offreQuantite(head(os))) (offrePrix(head(os))))
                          n= n-(offreQuantite(head(os)))
                          xs =  tail(os)
                      in  rfred a xs n (c:lc)
                 else let c= (Commande (offreFournisseur(head(os))) (achatArticle(a)) n (offrePrix(head(os))))
                          n= 0
                          xs =  tail(os) 
                      in  rfred a xs n (c:lc)
```

Comment: Please add some details to this question! What "it" is expected to do?

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful reply if (1) you add some information about what your code is supposed to do, and what result you expect, (2) you include your data declarations (what are `Achat` and `Commande` supposed to be?) and (3) you name your variables and functions in English.

Comment: At a guess: `offresPour` creates an infinite list, and `n` never reaches `0` (perhaps because `offreQuantite` returns zero or negative numbers a lot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in

```
let c= (Commande (offreFournisseur(head(os))) (achatArticle(a)) (offreQuantite(head(os))) (offrePrix(head(os))))
    n= n-(offreQuantite(head(os)))
    ^^^^^
```

The `n` on the right hand side is not the `n` from the test above, but the `n` introduced on the left hand side of the binding (which shadows the one from the outer scope). If `os (= offresPour achat1_1 [offre1_1_1_100])` contains more than one item, `n` is needed in the test

```
if os == []|| n==0
```

in the recursive call, and evaluation hangs.

Name the variable differently,

```
let c = ...
    n' = n - ...
in rfred ... n' ...
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! exactly my error! everything work perfectly now